# MPU-6050 Sensor Surface Mounting

Tags: sensors

I have purchased an MPU-6050 sensor to complete a project, and wish to mount it onto a PCB board. I have my PCB board, but the sensor I purchased does not have any legs extending out of it.

[MPU-6050 Chip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp2qj.jpg)

I am having trouble understanding how to mount this device onto the PCB. Would I have to add legs onto the MPU-6050 before soldering the chip onto the board? Or would it suffice to place the chip onto the PCB and create connections to sides of the MPU-6050 using solder.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a programming problem.

Comment: You may want to try electronics.stackexchange.com.